# Android; using exec("bugreport")

Tags: java, android, logging, exec

Is it possible to read the output of the terminal command `adb #bugreport` from within the application?

I tried the following but I couldn't manage to get any output.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bugreport");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
process.getInputStream()));
// Test result
Log.d(TAG, "Line: "+bufferedReader.readLine());
```

I know it works with `exec("logcat")`, but I prefer the output of `bugreport` as it contains more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A while ago I found the solution to this problem;

"bugreport" is a adb command it cannot be executed via the regular shell. But since adb just outputs: "logcat", "dumpsys" and "dumpstate" these commands can be run individually to achieve the same result.

Additional info:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#commandsummary

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about the bugreport command? I try to run it via the runtime exec but I can't collect the output.